# Python script not launchable from C# or by running .py

Tags: c#, python, process

Before you flag this as a repost, please read my issue xD I haven't been able to find any answers to my paticular question.

I'm trying to launch a Python script from a C# program. Now I've made and tested my Python script, and when running it from my IDE (Visual Studio 2017) it works perfectly. Now when I try to execute it as a process from my C# program, a command prompt briefly appears (when I say briefly it's more like it flashes on screen), but my script has not run.

The code for my python script:

```
import os
import shutil
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.table import Table
from pptx.text.text import TextFrame
from pptx.text.text import Pt
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

#Get ressources dir:
currentWorkingDir = os.getcwd()
ressourceDir = currentWorkingDir[:-31 ]

#Open files and read into variables
agendaInputFile = open(ressourceDir + "agendaInputs.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")

agendaInputs = agendaInputFile.readlines()

agendaTimesFile = open(ressourceDir + "agendaTimes.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")

agendaTimes = agendaTimesFile.readlines()

meetingTitleFile = open(ressourceDir + "meetingTitle.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")

meetingTitle = meetingTitleFile.readline()

presentersFile = open(ressourceDir + "presenters.txt", "r", encoding = "utf8")

presenters = presentersFile.readlines();

#Opens the template ppt-file
prs = Presentation(ressourceDir + "agendaTemplate.pptx")

#selects the first slide
slide = prs.slides[0]

#Sets the meetingtitle
title = slide.shapes[1]
title.text = meetingTitle[:-1]

#finds the table
graphicFrame = slide.shapes[2]
table = graphicFrame.table

#sætter agendapunkterne
i = 0
while i < len(agendaInputs):
    cell = table.cell(i+1,1)
    textFrame = cell.text_frame
    run = textFrame.paragraphs[0].add_run()
    font = run.font
    font.name = 'TSTAR PRO'
    font.size = Pt(16)
    run.text = agendaInputs[i][:-1]
    font.color.theme_color = 5
    i += 1

#Sætter agendatiderne
i = 0
while i < len(agendaTimes):
    cell = table.cell(i+1,0)
    textFrame = cell.text_frame
    run = textFrame.paragraphs[0].add_run()
    font = run.font
    font.name = 'TSTAR PRO'
    font.size = Pt(16)
    run.text = agendaTimes[i][:-1]
    font.color.theme_color = 5
    i += 1

#Sætter presenter
i = 0
while i < len(presenters):
    cell = table.cell(i+1,2)
    textFrame = cell.text_frame
    run = textFrame.paragraphs[0].add_run()
    font = run.font
    font.name = 'TSTAR PRO'
    font.size = Pt(16)
    run.text = presenters[i][:-1]
    font.color.theme_color = 5
    i += 1

#saves the ppt
prs.save("Agenda Slide.pptx")

#File is deleted from the desktop if present there
if os.path.exists("Agenda Slide.txt"):
    os.remove("Agenda Slide.txt")

#File moved to the desktop
shutil.move(os.getcwd() + "\\Agenda Slide.pptx", os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop") + "\\Agenda Slide.pptx")
```

Now, as I said, when I launch this from my IDE it works like a charm.

The files that I open and read in the python script is written to by my C# program. This is a lowtech way of transfering variables from my C# to my Python, not pretty, I know.. xD

From my c# programme this is how I launch the script:

```
private void runPythonScript()
        {
            Process p = new Process(); // create process (i.e., the python program
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Python34\python.exe";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = getRessourcesDir() + "createAgendaPPT\\createAgendaPPT\\createAgendaPPT.py";                  
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            p.Close();
        }
```

The function `getRessourcesDir()` just returns the directory for the Ressources folder in the solution.

So to sum up:

- Trying to launch a python script from C#
- Pythonscript will run correctly from my IDE but not by launching the .py file.

What I need help for:
How to make a python script launchable from it's .py file and how to launch it from C#.

If anything is unclear or missing, please let me know and I will edit my post and correct it.

Comment: Try running it from the `cmd` shell command line.

Comment: @martineau when I try to do that it gives the error "C:\python34\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\aalbaek-nt\Desktop\createAgendaPPT.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory." But I'm absolutely sure that I give it the right directories...

Comment: You should be able to determine if the gave it something valid by entering `dir C:\Users\aalbaek-nt\Desktop\createAgendaPPT.py` to see. Typing `dir C:\Users\aalbaek-nt\Desktop` alone will list all the files in the folder.

Comment: @martineau 
When I run that command it says "File not found", so I'm guessing that the shortcut might be where it fails? Would it be a problem that the file `createAgendaPPT` on the desktop is a shortcut to the real file? The reason for this is that am using the `os.getcwd()' function to locate the directory of some files that I'm using, and by moving the file I'm afraid that it wont target the right directory anymore.

Comment: Yoy should be able to right-click on the icon for `xxx` on your desktop and select "Properties" which will cause a dialog box to appear with information about the object. If it's a shortcut then it will say so and also show you the location of the real file—that's the path you want to use.

Comment: @martineau yeah, I know, but the thing is that the path to the real .py file contains the danish letter Æ, which CMD has a hard time interpreting..

Comment: You may be able to workaround that by using a "symbolic link" which Windows 10 supports. They'll make the file look more like they really are in the `Desktop` folder. You may have to look-up (Windows Help?) how to do so if you don't know it already.

Comment: Sounds like a good feature! I'll look it up! Thank you for your help @martineau!!

Answer (score 0):

Try running python script from a command window.

```
        Process cmdProcess;
        StreamWriter cmdStreamWriter;
        StreamReader cmdStreamReader;
        cmdProcess = new Process();
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;


        cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmdProcess.Start();

        cmdStreamWriter = cmdProcess.StandardInput;
        cmdStreamReader = cmdProcess.StandardOutput;

        cmdStreamWriter.WriteLine("python xxxx.py");
```

Comment: From review: could you please add more detail to your answer? The code you posted does not make any sense...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't seem to work either.. When I copy and paste your code into my function and change the "xxxx" in the last line to: "createAgendaPPT", nothing happens when I call the function.

Comment: Your python script must be in the your build directory(Debug or Release).

Comment: @T.Aalbaek This worked for me actually don't know what is wrong. Try opening a cmd window in debug directory and run your python script manually.